# Java web service invoking a stored pocedure

Tags: web-services

Does anybody have a example Java web srevice to invoke a stored procedure in the database.

Answer (score 0):

A java webservice shouldn't connect directly to a database, but go through a database layer.

For java to use a stored procedure use the `prepareCall` method in JDBC as seen here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html

Comment: Thanks i would also like to know once i create a class to invoke a stored procedure how do i annotate that java class to make it a web service

Comment: @lisa - Which version of java, and how to write a webservice is a different question.

Comment: You may want to get jax-ws, as it doesn't come with JDK5 as it does with JDK6. Here is a tutorial on using this: http://blogs.oracle.com/artf/entry/a_simple_howto_of_web